# LibGDX animation is flickering when flipped

Tags: animation, libgdx, flicker, flip

Hi I have an animation in my LibGDX game that flickers when flipped.
So it switches really fast (like every frame) from flipped and not flipped and i know that the flip variable is not changing. Here's the code:

```
@Override
public void render(SpriteBatch sb, float a) {

    updateDrawVariables(a);

    if (isWalking) {
        walkStateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    }

    TextureRegion frame = walk.getKeyFrame(walkStateTime, true);

    if (flip) {
        frame.flip(true, false);
    }


    sb.draw(frame, drawX, drawY, drawWidth, drawHeight);
    if (Main.DEBUG)Resources.font.draw(sb, "HP: " + health, drawX, drawY);

}
```

Any answers is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
frame.flip(true, false);
```

This will always flip the texture region from it's current state. So it will be flipped one frame, not flipped the next and then flipped again.

You want something like

```
frame.flip(!frame.isFlipX(), frame.isFlipY());
```